# What 's the cleaner way to declare a list of constant messages in java spring?

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to declare the messages :

- in a  PropertyPlaceholder in my context file
- in a  ResourceBundleMessageSource
- in a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
- anything else?

By now I think of a message.properties file like the way I define labels in a webapp. Defining every label in a message.properties file like :

```
D01_F01_FL002_CU01_FE01_ERREUR8 =
    "idFiche null ou incorrect. Veuillez vérifier que l’identifiant de la fiche commence par I ou A ou M."
```

But it seems that Spring has better ways to define labels than properties files in a ResourceBundle, using annotation or application-context file by instance.